# Prevent floated right nav bar from moving when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm required to make sure my nav bar remains on the right of my header such that the user utilises the horizontal scroll bar to access the navigation options which aren't visible.

Currently I've got 5 elements in my nested  and once the user resizes the browser the nav menu jumps/moves down.

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1274/)

HTML:

```
<header> <!-- Navigation menu bar -->
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>

    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

        <ul> <!-- Navigation menu bar options. These are fixed in terms of content. -->
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactus">Extras</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>          
        </ul>

    </nav>              
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90%;
}

#logo {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 86px;
    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
    display: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 86px;
    background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}   

a:hover#menu-icon {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just put a min-width on your header element, stopping it from ever becoming too narrow for the list elements to fit, yet retaining the flexibility.

I tried min-width:660px; and it seemed to work fine to me.

```
header {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 660px;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90%;
}
```

ALTERNATELY you can change your nav css to

```
nav {
    text-align:right;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

..And then change your header's "height" to "min-height" instead.

Comment: header {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    min-width: 660px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90%;
}

Comment: Do you mean as above? As the nav is behaving the same way .. its jumping when I re-size the browser to a width of 800px or less .. here's my updated fidlle

Comment: Yes, exactly. It worked for me. Let me know if you encounter any problem.

Comment: I've attempted is as a fiddle and it works but it weirdly wrapping when i insert it into my main page .. here's the fiddle to my full page .. https://jsfiddle.net/q46Xz/946/

Comment: Well that's because your id=logo element in your "header" is too wide, it's pushing things to the next row. A neat trick you could use is adding *{outline:1px solid black;} to the beginning of your CSS. This gives all elements a border so you can see their position and dimensions.

Comment: Your nav-element is 553px wide and your logo is 200px wide, so you need to set the min-width of "header" to 753px atleast, or else they won't fit inside.
If you think it's okay for the individual links to drop, but not the whole nav row together, I suggest you replace the float:right on nav with text-align:right instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the natural flexibility of the menu by adding a specific width. That way, regardless of the size of the browser window, the menu will remain the width you want it to be and the user will have to scroll to see it.

You can use JS to dynamically do this by setting the width of the header to be a certain amount of pixels, for e.g., greater than whatever is the width of the window upon loading of the document and resizing of the window.

Comment: Thanks ..... i'll give that a try ... but any ideas as how to  dynamically set the width of the header ...

Comment: Are you sure MY answer doesn't satisfy? No JS, only one line of CSS, if I understood your Q.

Comment: Waltur's answer works just fine. I had only assumed scrollbars were desired. Also, as his fiddle shows, the menu grows in height, which, as far as I know, tends to be undesirable, hence the hamburger icon being added in media queries to ensure the menu is accessible when the normal version cannot fit. As for the JS to dynamically set the width: acquire the width of the window, set a fixed width for the menu section of the header, then decide a set width for the rest of the menu, and, depending on the width of the window, increase the width of that section with JS to retain some responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS Table display to sort the layout in the header and stop the menu from wrapping underneath. (added bonus: this avoids `floats` altogether)

```
header {
    display: table;
}
header #logo, header nav {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/S5bKq/1277/

As for the responsive menu itself - a quick internet search for 'responsive menus' will net you several examples/tutorials.